# WiFi+Bluetooth problem

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth

I bought an HP 15-203TX DOS laptop and installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 which I downloaded from the Ubuntu website.

On starting, the WiFi gets connected and works only for several minutes, then it's connected but data/packets are not working.

Bluetooth is also not detecting any device nor gets detected by any other device.

When I changed my desktop background more errors occur.
words missing from icons and list items.

After restarting, the wifi again works for a few minutes then goes off.
words remain  missing some time and sometime works fine.

The output of wireless-info can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10739644/).

Comment: What's Ubuntu 14.02? There are only 14.04 and 14.10.

Comment: sorry ...it's Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. And change the Ubuntu release version. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the bluetooth will only work after installing modules from Larry Fingers Github site

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
cd ~
git clone -b troy https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt.git
cd rtl8723au_bt-troy
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Since these are built only for the current kernel, a kernel update will cause bluetooth to quit functioning and your wifi may revert to having issues, when that happens

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make clean
make
sudo make install

cd ~/rtl8723au_bt-troy
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Comment: Thanks Jeremy31

bluetooth has started working now.It's working fine when I have to send some items but while receiving it's its not working.A lock symbol comes on bluetooth symbol and it gets disconnected with device and transfer fails.And after failure, connection is established again and I can send data to device but can't receive it.
Any suggestion.

Comment: search dash for personal file sharing and enable bluetooth to receive files to downloads folder